# Theme namespaces Android

Tags: android, xamarin, styles, material-design

I expended days looking for any documentation and really don't figured out not even how to start.

What I am looking for is the namespaces, i want to custom somethings on android, so I read that i can override the Material style, but how can I override it if i can't find the namespaces and what they do?

take a look here:

i Created my Style:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="VogoSocialTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/VogoSocialTheme.AlertDialog</item>
  </style>

  <style name="VogoSocialTheme.AlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#122f54</item>
  </style>

  <!-- Colors -->
  <color name="primary">#2764B5</color>
  <color name="primary_dark">#B2f91816</color>
  <color name="accent">#122f54</color>

</resources>
```

everything here I just I copied and pasted, but now i want to for example change the background color, size of text, or whatever, so probably I need to change the

```
  <style name="VogoSocialTheme.AlertDialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:colorAccent">#122f54</item>
  </style>
```

and add a new items with specific name **android:...**
where can i find theses names and docs to go ahead ?

Answer (score 1):

[R.style reference](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

> The R.style reference, however, is **not well documented** and **does not thoroughly describe** the styles, so viewing the actual source code for these styles and themes will give you a better understanding of what style properties each one provides. For a better reference to the Android styles and themes, see the following source code:

[Source styles.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml)

[Source themes.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml)

Ref: [Using Platform Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#PlatformStyles)

Comment: Well, at least i have the names, I guess kkkk. I'll take a better look in those files and see what i can do. 
Thx!

Comment: @NicollasBraga At least Google documents that they have not documented it well :-/